# Pointer to an array type (custom types)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, typedef

I have a custom array type defined as in the code and a pointer to that array type also defined. I'm trying to find a correlation between the custom array type and a pointer to the custom array type. How do I assign a value to the pointer of the custom array type so I can iterate through the array using the pointer?

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef int array_type[3];
typedef array_type* ptr_array_type;

int main() {
   array_type a = {2,3,4};
   ptr_array_type ptr;

   ptr = a;

   printf("%d\n",*ptr);

}
```

I know the array name contains the pointer to the first element. I keep getting an invalid printout: 
-50204788 instead of 2.

I also get a warning:

warning: assignment to 'ptr_array_type' {aka 'int (*)[3]'} from incompatible pointer type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    ptr = a;

Could someone point me in the right way to assign a proper value to the pointer so I can iterate through the array.

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef.  It's much more prone to confusing (people) than to helping.

Comment: You are assigning type `T` to `T*` variable. These are incompatible. And the fact `T` is array does not change it.

Comment: The type of `*ptr` is `int[3]`.  This decays to a *pointer to* the first element, which is not at all equivalent to the *value of* the first element.

Comment: The code is actually from an autosar project where types are defined as that, and now I'm trying to figure out how are they assigned.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I assign a value to the pointer of the custom array type so I
>   can iterate through the array using the pointer?

Given `array_type` defined by

```
typedef int array_type[3];
```

, the pointer type to which you can assign an `array_type` is `int *`:

```
typedef int *ptr_array_element;
```

You can (seemingly) assign an object of `array_type` to a pointer of type `ptr_array_element`:

```
array_type a = {2, 3, 4};
ptr_array_element p = a;
```

Having done so, you can access the first array element via the derferencing operator.

```
assert(*p == 2);
```

And you can generally use it a bit like a C++ iterator:

```
printf("%d\n", *p++);
printf("%d\n", *p++);
printf("%d\n", *p++);
```

**BUT DON'T.**

Use typedefs sparingly, where they hide irrelevant detail, substantially improve code clarity, or similar.  Avoid using typedefs that obscure *relevant* details, such as that objects of that type are pointers or arrays, unless, possibly, those details are abundantly clear from the type names, or unless hiding them is intentional and harmless.  It is rarely harmless to hide array or pointer nature.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` is a pointer to `int[3]`; `a` *is* an `int[3]`.  While I don't like `typedef`ing pointer types in general, if you insist on this approach, here's how you can dereference into the first element of `a` from `ptr`:

```
ptr = &a;
printf("%d\n", **ptr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you explain the solution a little more in depth. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the code I actually don't understand the first typedef for the array type. How can that be written without typedefing?

Answer (score 0):

`ptr_array_type` aliases `int (*)[3]`, not `int *` - you will not be able to use it to iterate through `array_type`.  You *could* use it to iterate through an *array* of `array_type`, like so:

```
array_type arr[3];
ptr_array_type ptr = arr;

while ( size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
  do_something_with( ptr[i] );
```

If you want to be able to iterate through an array of `T` with a pointer, then the type of that pointer must be `T *`.  So you'd need to change your typedefs to something like

```
typedef int array_type[3];    // probably want to replace int with another
typedef int *ptr_array_type;  // typedef to abstract out the type
...
array_type a = {1, 2, 3}; // yuck! don't do this! a is not obviously an array,
                          // so an array initializer looks wrong in this context
ptr_my_type p = a;

printf( "%d", *p );
```

However...

If you're using `typedef` to abstract away implementation details for a type, then you should abstract away *all* implementation details for that type, including things like dereferencing and subscripting.  You'll want to create a full API, such as:

```
 array_type *arr = new_array_type( 1, 2, 3 );  // even this is leaky since it assumes we know
                                               // the array element type is integral
 array_type_iterator *itr = new_array_type_iterator( arr );
 array_element_type target;

 begin_iterator( &itr ); 
 while( next_iterator( &itr ) )
 {
   get_data_from_iterator( itr, &target );
   write_array_element_to( stdout, target );
 }

 free_array_type_iterator( itr );
 free_array_type( arr );
```

Partial or leaky abstractions just lead to code that's confusing to use and maintain.  If the user of a type has to be aware of that type's "array-ness" or "pointer-ness" in order to use it properly, then don't hide those qualities behind a typedef without providing replacements for the `[]` and unary `*` operators as well.  Also provide some way to abstract out I/O - don't force the user to have to know whether to use `%d` or `%f` or `%s` in a `printf` statement if they're not working with a primitive type.